# Функция срабатывает только один раз

Tags: гаджет, javascript, html

Здравствуйте!

Такая вообщем проблема: делаю гаджет, в который при нажатии кнопки подгружается контент, при включении гаджета, в `body` срабатывает функция `load()`, которая подгружает информацию, а вот при нажатии кнопки, с навешанной той же функции ничего не происходит, вот код:

`javascript`

```
function load() {
    $.get("http://mirella8.ru/gadget/work.php?callback=", function (data) {
        $("#frame").html(data);
    });
}
```

`HTML`

```
<body onload="load();">
<div id="frame"></div>
<button onclick="load();" >Обновить</button>
</body>
```

Код рабочий, но не работает в IE, при загрузке страницы `load()` срабатывает, а вот при нажатии кнопки нет. `:(`

Comment: Ну помогите, плизззз))

Comment: А с чего вы решили, что не отрабатывает? в `callback` добавьте `alert('lol');`

А еще проверьте, что в `#frame` не подгружаются конфликтующие скрипты. Вероятность наличия в них функции "`load`" довольно высока)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

KiTE прав, если уж пользоваться jQuery, то до конца!

И потом, код-то рабочий. Просто, вследствие того, что полученный объект не изменяется не видно и изменений при нажатии на кнопку.
Если к функции load() добавить параметр, какой-нить при нажатии на кнопку, видно что все работает:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function load(s){
  $.get("http://localhost/stam/get.html", function(data){
    $("#frame").html(data + s);
  });
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="load('');">
<div id="frame"></div>
<button onclick="load('sss');" >Обновить</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Попробуй воспользоваться стандартными конструкциями фреймворка:

```
jQuery(function($){});
```

или

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){});
```

Например:

```
jQuery(function($){
    var load = function(){
        $.get("http://mirella8.ru/gadget/work.php?callback=", function(data){
            $("#frame").html(data);
        });
    };
    $('#btn').click(load);
    load();
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="frame"></div>
<button id="btn">Обновить</button>
```

Comment: Ошииииииибка :) Если нужно будет воспользщоваться конструкцией как у Михи Николаева ( вызов функции из другого элемента, например, по клику), load опять же не отработает :)) KiTE, думаем почему ?:)

Comment: Потому что она объявлена как локальная. Зато можно ее записхнуть в `window.tools.load` и все будет хорошо.

Comment: Не ошибка, а опечатка :)

Тегу `<button>` нужно назначить `id` и обработку клика вешать на него. Исправил. [Тут][1] упрощенный вариант.

  [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/4dmVZ/

Answer (score 2):

А смысл делать так ?

Может так лучше ? (не идеально, но все же проще)

```
var Startup = {

__url: "",
__data: {},
__target: "",
// Инициализация
constructor: function (url, data, target) {
    this.setUrl(url);
    this.setData(data);
    this.setTarget(target);
    this.regListeners();
            this.remote();
},
// Сюда заносим все листенеры данного объекта
regListeners: function () {
    jQuery("button_id").click( function () {
        Startup.remote();
    });
},
/** Функция запроса 
*  @param url   - URL
*  @data    - параметры запроса (object) 
*  @target  - Куда вставить 
*/
remote: function (url, data, target) {
    if(!url) var url = this.getUrl();
    if(!data) var data = this.getData();
    if(!target) var target = this.getTarget();
    var str = "?";
    if(typeof(data) == "object") {
        for (i in data) {
            if(str.length > 1)
                str += "&";
            str += i + "=" + data[i];
        }
    }
    var url = this.getUrl + str;
    jQuery.get(url, str, function (e) {
        jQuery("#" + target).html(e);
    });
},
setUrl: function (e) {
    this.__url = e;
},
getUrl: function () {
    return this.__url;
},
getData: function () {
    return this.__data;
},
setData: function (e) {
    if(typeof(e) != "object")
        return false;   
    this.__data = e;
}
```

}

Использование
    <script>

```
var url = "http://mirella8.ru/gadget/work.php";
        var params = { callback: ""};
        var target = "frame";
        jQuery(document).ready( function () { Startup.constructor(url, params, target) });
</script>
```

Comment: "Проще"?!!

Comment: Конечно проще. Короче код - не факт что проще.

Comment: В этом случае, явно, не проще.

Зачем вполне читабельный код из 10 строк размазывать на несколько листингов? Тем более, когда, в любом случае, используется jQuery.

Comment: :) Вот когда будешь писать большие проекты - поймешь :))
Нужно код писать таким образом, чтобы он не обрабатывал определенную ситуацию, но и мог подходить для использования в других случаях.

P.S. А где мой код нечитабелен ? 
P.P.S. Код более универсален.
P.P.P.S. Я сказал - это далеко не идеальный вариант. Более идеальным был бы еще больший объем кода.

Comment: На счет повторного использования кода. Существует масса вариантов: библиотеки функций, разработка плагинов, использование архитектуры типа MVC. В вопросе об этом ни слова.

Простой вопрос, подразумевает простой ответ. Человеку нужна лопатка чтобы вырыть ямку, а ты ему экскаватор.

З.Ы.: Я уже давно участвую в разработке больших проектов...

Comment: :) При этом до недавноего времени не знал про замыкание ? :))) ладно, ответом ему надавали, пусть думает. Се, не ссоримс/я

Comment: Жесть**.**

Comment: @Станислав Комар, речь не о JavaScript. Опыт - кроссплатформенная штука. Чтобы изучить новый язык, достаточно вникнуть только в его особенности. Базовые конструкции и общая архитектура везде одинакова.

И, не пойму, к чему твой последний коммент? Это не тот форум где удобно и осмысленно разводить срач и троллинг.

Comment: Я использовал данный мне пример, спасибо работает, но инфа обновлялась только 2 раза :( , потом решил добавить в коллбэк случайное число и все сразу заработало))) Спасибо)))

Answer (score 2):

1. Если обращение идет к другому домену, то так нельзя. ajax работает в пределах одного домена. Да, есть оговорки, но в простейшем случае именно так: нельзя ходить за чужим контентом. [Здесь](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/javascript/120336/) подробно расписано как с этим справляться, если действительно нужно.
2. Используя jQuery, действительно лучше писать в стиле jQuery `$(document).ready(function(){ ... });` и `$("btn").click( ... );` Код в этом случае будет отделен от разметки и искать его будет легче.
    2.1. Достаточно написать `$("#frame").load("content.php");` вместо `$.get(...)`, хотя если нужен колбэк в котором делается что-то кроме загрузки в frame данных, то и get сойдет, правда нагляднее использовать `$.ajax`, imho.
3. Да, все работает и в IE тоже ))

Comment: В концептуальном плане по 1-му пункту вы абсолютно правы. Но начиная с версии JQuery 1.4.4 в `.ajax()` появилась поддержка кроссдоменных запросов. В стандартном случае, если в URL есть параметр `callback`, то этот запрос формируется и обрабатывается по принципу JSONP. Честь и хвала разработчикам за стандартизацию, хоть это и может вводить в заблуждение.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov безусловно Вы правы, но так, как у меня сдесь стоит коллбэк то это уже значит, что я совершаю запрос к другому домену, и запрос успешно проходит.

Comment: Да и с проблемой уже справился

Comment: Ну в примере был не jsonp, а обычный текст, поэтому и засомневался в правильности идеи. jsonp с других доменов работает по другому принципу, нежели обычный ajax, т.е не через XmlHttpRequest, это надо иметь в виду и ошибку возможной неработы уже надо будет искать в ответе, а не в коде...

Comment: Тоже смотрел, через браузер - выдача текстовая. Может серверная сторона проверяет какой-то http-заголовок и на ajax-запрос из jQuery возвращает json в callback-обертке?..

Comment: Все может быть, главное автору надо иметь в виду, что если ответ сервера будет произвольным, а не строго jsonp, то будут слабоуловимые баги...